# How would I solve a system of equations for a constrained Optimization problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis

[my intial work on the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn0M5.jpg) I appoligize, I do not quite know how to use math formatting for this post.

I've been toying with this problem for a few days. I must have attempted to solve it in 4 different ways. Essentially we have a constrained optimization problem given by:

f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2 , constrained by x^2+16y^2=16 = g(x,y)

Please see the attached picture for some of my intial thoughts/workings.

I'm trying to disect my main problem when it comes to solving for λ. I can set up my system of three equations with the last equation being my g(x,y). Every video/notes I see online in which they attempt to solve for λ works out with the gradient of f(x,y) being a function of x, and grad(g(x,y)) either being a constant, or a function of (y,z) for example. I understand that case.

> If L(x,y,λ) = grad(f)-λ(grad(g)), then grad(f)=λ(grad(g)). In this particular case I can see my first equation is 2x=λ(2x)

I hope this plus the picture was specfic enough to get any advice on this problem! I'm here to answer any further questions!

tldr: how do i solve for λ given the system

> 2x=λ(2x) , 3y=λ(32y) , 16=x^2+16y^2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks José! I will take a look at them now. I’m a bit of a code nerd but never got around to any mathjax et. Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem you can see the solution fairly easily. Reparametrize with $u=x^2$ and $v=y^2$. You then have the additional condition that $u \geq 0$ and $v \geq 0$. Now,
$$\max_{u,v} u + 2v$$
$$\text{s.t.} \quad u + 16 v = 16$$
$$ u \geq 0, \quad v \geq 0$$
has solution $u=16$, $v=0$. Pull this back into $x= \pm 4, y=0$.

If you want to do this the calculus way, plug this solution in to get $\lambda=1$ in your equations. In this case it's a bit easier to justify the solution you know you should end up with.

I assumed that you are maximizing your objective, but you never wrote whether you are maximizing or minimizing. For minimization, it works the same way but the solution is $u=0$, $v=1$.

Comment: Hi @robert, I see you edited and the clarification helped. The way you solved it is accurate. While I knew the answer to the problem I was left with a gap of why so the explanation was helpful. My initial reaction was to reduce the equation, for the first two you get c* λ. In the first equation 2x is eliminated letting me know λ=1 I the second case I can see λ=1/8. Either way very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve done most of the work. Just express
$$
\nabla f(x) = \lambda\nabla g(x)
$$
as
$$
Ax = \lambda Bx,\quad A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix},\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&16\end{pmatrix},
$$
then solve the eigenvalue problem
$B^{-1}Ax=\lambda x$. In your case it’s really easy, since the matrix on the left is diagonal.

Comment: Oh wow, what an elegant thought for the solution. Can I ask a follow up out of pure interest. Is the Lagrangian multiplier in essence the same and/or related to the eigenvalue? Do they simply share a letter or is there more intrinsic crossover?

Comment: @AaronWeymouth well, we’re optimising a quadratic function over an ellipsoidal region, so yes we would expect to do something with eigenvalues/eigenvectors :p  otherwise, I can’t think of an intricate connection between the two, although duality theory is pretty rich, and you’d be surprised how many weird mathematical relationships can be found there.